# Need to merge multiple data together by using CDK drag & drop

Tags: angular, angular-material, drag-and-drop, angular-cdk

I had created an application which requires drag & drop feature in it. I had implemented the CDK drag & drop in it because it's easier for me to use. The drag & drop feature works fine for me but I had another requirement to merge multiple of them together. I had tried a lot but unable to find any solution for. I don't know whether I want to try some other libraries or something.

Comment: Could you please elaborate what you mean by "merge"?

Comment: need to add two or more division data together